# Getting CSV values from Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, hash

I am trying to convert Javascript object to CSV and store it in to a file..
I have a demo: http://jsbin.com/atewix/8/edit

What I want to do is If I give the entity values "Time" or "News" inside function `findProps()`,

It should return CSV in the format:

```
"http://www.testingmyurl.com", Time, Dec 9, 2012
```

or

```
"http://www.testingmyurl.com",News, Germany,Election
"http://www.testingmyurl.com",News,Egypt, Revolution
```

with the current format it returns only individual values and that too as `[object,object]`

```
{
"_index": "test",
"_source": {
     "link": "http://www.testingmyurl.com",
  "Categories": {
      "Types": {
          "Events": [{
              "count": 1,
              "entity": "Time",
              "Time": [{
                  "entity": "Dec 9",
                  "Dec_9": [{
                      "count": 1,
                      "entity": "2012"
                  }]
                  }]
              }]}}}}
```

Can this be turned in to a flat structure?

Comment: Your nested Object does not seem to be cleanly representable as CSV.

Comment: any suggestion for the change in structure

Comment: No - If you have a non-flat structure, it won't be possible to represent it as a two-dimensional array (which csv essentially is). You will need to know how you'd want to present your structure in excel - I don't.

Comment: @Bergi Ive editd the question part..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty deep structure, but this function will work with your data as-is. The `fixSpace()` function accounts for the discrepancy between `Dec 9` and `Dec_9`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/r2kje/

#### Output:

```
News:
"http://www.testingmyurl.com","News","Germany","Election"
"http://www.testingmyurl.com","News","Egypt","Revolution"
Time:
"http://www.testingmyurl.com","Time","Dec 9","2012"
```

#### Script:

```js
function findProps( name, data ) {
    var results = [],
        events = data._source.Categories.Types.Events,
        link = data._source.link;

    for( var eventIndex = 0; eventIndex < events.length; eventIndex++ ) {
        var event = events[eventIndex];
        if( event.entity == name && event[name]  ) {
            for( var entityIndex = 0; entityIndex < event[name].length; entityIndex++ ) {
                var entity = event[name][entityIndex],
                    entityName = fixSpace( entity.entity );
                if( entity[entityName] ) {
                    for( var valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < entity[entityName].length; valueIndex++ ) {
                        var value = entity[entityName][valueIndex];
                        results.push( 
                              '"' + link + '",'
                            + '"' + name + '",'
                            + '"' + entity.entity + '",' //un-fixSpaced name
                            + '"' + value.entity + '"'
                        );
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };

    return results;
};

function fixSpace( value ) {
    return value.replace( ' ', '_' );        
};

var news = findProps( "News", data );
document.getElementById( 'news' ).innerHTML = news.join( '<br />' );
var times = findProps( "Time", data );
document.getElementById( 'time' ).innerHTML = times.join( '<br />' );
```

HTML:

```html
News:
<div id="news"></div>
Time:
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: what if the depth of Time or News array are not fixed, what if it goes to level more than 3..

Comment: @user1371896 The function can be modified to handle that. You could even make it recursive. Better would be to make your data structure flatter. It's way too deep.

Comment: Is recursion possible with this structure.. Will you be able to show me how it can be done? or should I add one more question and post the link in comments?

Comment: @user1371896 The two inner structures, entity and value, are exactly the same. If deeper structures follow this same pattern, you can simply add more levels of `for()`. Edit your question with the deeper structures you're thinking of, and what results you'd expect, and I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ive updated the expctd output and json... the result should go on addding at the end no matter how deep the Json is